# How do I find out which version of Doctrine I am running?

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine, doctrine-orm, doctrine-1.2

Have been using it for a while with CodeIgniter and I can't remember if I installed v2 or just copied the files from another project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Check out the file `vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Version.php`, there is a constant in there that shows the version. It's also accessible from a running app but this is easier.

Comment: This does not apply for Symfony 5*. I guess this file exists on Symfony 3 or 4.

Comment: I'm on Symfony 3.4 using Doctrine 2.5, and the file is vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Version.php.

Comment: in sf 6, the path  change a little :`vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Version.php`, I run from my project folder : `cd vendor/doctrine/orm/ && grep -rn VERSION`

Answer (score 42):

If you are using the composer to handle dependencies on your project, then you should try with:

```
php composer.phar show --installed
```

OR

```
php composer.phar show -i | grep doctrine
```

And the output will be something like:

```
doctrine/annotations                     v1.1.2             Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                           v1.3.0             Caching library offering an object-oriented API for many cache backends
doctrine/collections                     v1.2               Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                          v2.4.1             Common Library for Doctrine projects
doctrine/data-fixtures                   v1.0.0             Data Fixtures for all Doctrine Object Managers
doctrine/dbal                            2.3.4              Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle                 v1.2.0             Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle        v2.2.0             Symfony DoctrineFixturesBundle
doctrine/inflector                       v1.0               Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/lexer                           v1.0               Base library for a lexer that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Parsers.
doctrine/orm                             2.3.5              Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
```

Comment: `php composer.phar show --installed` gave error `Could not open input file: composer.phar` (I ran it from the repo top-level folder). I had to run `composer show --installed | grep doctrine`.

Answer (score 8):

Within my **symfony2** and **symfony3** project, **the path** to find the correct **Version.php** file, line 39, was:

> Vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Version.php

Answer (score 6):

`core.php`:

```
class Doctrine_Core
{
    /**
     * VERSION
     */
    const VERSION                   = '1.2.4';

...
```

Comment: Thanks, for those who want to find core.php, you can check in you project source or in your symfony default installation: ...\php5\PEAR\symfony\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine

Answer (score 5):

For Windows users:

Within your symfony2 project:

```
\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Version.php
```

look for something like:

```
/**
 * Current Doctrine Version
 */
const VERSION = '2.4.6';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have composer installed using your PATH for its executable, you may get an error that composer.phar doesn't exist.

This works for me:

`% composer show --installed | grep "doctrine/orm"`

You should get output showing the version number:

```
You are using the deprecated option "installed". Only installed packages are shown by default now. The --all option can be used to show all packages.
doctrine/orm                             v2.5.14 Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
```

Note that you don't need the `| grep` part; if you remove that, you'll see all installed things from composer in the project. You can instead use `| grep doctrine` to see all Doctrine-related installed package versions.

Answer (score 0):

For Doctrine version 1.* open file /doctrine/Doctrine/Core.php

Should see version number at the begging.